# Node/Express - POST submit with end response without page render/redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I still learning but a bit frustrated that I can't find a solution for this issue using ES6 Javascript.

I have a simple todo-list web-app and everything is saved and rendered via the javascript file that's served with the html page and localstorage.

My issue is that I would like to be able to deploy it as a node app have online and offline usage. My idea to be able to add a task that will render client-side and make POST and DELETE request behind the scenes to be sent to a database.

The model is being received and saved exactly how I want it, however I want to end the response (res) so the page does not have to reload and break the application experience. The code does work using `res.redirect('back')` but does not without issues visually because it's reloading every time.

This is the app js file:

```
const express       = require('express');
const mongoose      = require('mongoose');
const passport      = require('passport');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const keys          = require('./config/keys');
const authRoutes    = require('./routes/auth-routes');
const passportSetup = require('./config/passport-setup');

//App
const app = express();

app.set('view engine','ejs');

//Static Files Route
app.use('/resources',express.static('resources'))

//CookieSession
app.use(cookieSession({
    maxAge: 1000*60*60*24,
    keys:   [keys.session.cookieKey]
}));

//Init passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//MongoDB Connect
mongoose.connect(keys.mongodb.dbURI,{ useNewUrlParser: true },()=>{console.log('MongoDB connected');})

//Routes
app.use('/auth',authRoutes);
app.use('/submit',require('./routes/submit'));

//Main
app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    res.render('index',{user: req.user});
});

//Port Listening
app.listen(7000, ()=>{
    console.log("Listening on port 7000");
});
```

This is the POST logic I'm working with:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Task = require('../models/task-model');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ exstended:false });

router.post('/', urlencodedParser, (req,res,next)=>{
    let newTask = Object.assign({owner: req.user._id},req.body);
    console.log("POST recieved");
    console.log(newTask);
    res.redirect('back');
    //Task.create(newTask);
});

module.exports = router;
```

The offline version of the webapp repo: https://github.com/FalseProspect/myTask-TODO-app/tree/master

TLDR;
Is it possible to end the pending server response without redirecting/rendering the same page using ES6 (no JQuery). I want nothing to happen to the page as a response from the sever.

Comment: Did you try res.end()?

Comment: You could just to res.sendStatus(200). This'll send a 200 back to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In your post method, use res.json()

```
return res.json({
    success: true,
    message: "Some success message",
    data: "some data if there's any"
});
```

In your front-end, check the response status or success value.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to send response from backend api call without redirecting and few different ways are like

Use .send

```
router.post('/', urlencodedParser, (req,res,next)=>{
    let newTask = Object.assign({owner: req.user._id},req.body);
    res.send('POST recieved', 200);
    res.end();
});
```

Different way of sending response using .send

```
router.post('/', urlencodedParser, (req,res,next)=>{
    let newTask = Object.assign({owner: req.user._id},req.body);
    res.status(200).send('POST recieved');
    res.end();
});
```

Different way of sending response using .send

```
router.post('/', urlencodedParser, (req,res,next)=>{
    let newTask = Object.assign({owner: req.user._id},req.body);
    res.send({"status": 200, "message": "POST recieved", "newTask": newTask});
    res.end();
});
```

Use .json to send the response

```
router.post('/', urlencodedParser, (req,res,next)=>{
    let newTask = Object.assign({owner: req.user._id},req.body);
    res.json({"status": 200, "message": "POST recieved", "newTask": newTask});
});
```

Use .write to send the response

```
 router.post('/', urlencodedParser, (req,res,next)=>{
    let newTask = Object.assign({owner: req.user._id},req.body);
    res.write({"status": 200, "message": "POST recieved", "newTask": newTask});
    res.write(200);
    res.write("POST recieved");
    res.write(newTask);
    res.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the responses, however most of them I had done prior to posting the question and they each would result in the page going white using `res.end()` or a blank page with the status or json in plain text.

My solution was to use Multiparty instead of body-parser and send formData via XMLHttpRequest instead of `form.submit()`.

Original:

```
function post(obj) {
  let form = document.createElement("form");
  form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
  form.setAttribute("action", '/');

  //Create temp form with obj data
  for(let key in obj) {
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          let hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "text");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", obj[key]);

          form.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
  }
  document.body.appendChild(form);  
  form.submit();
  document.body.removeChild(form);
}
```

Updated:

```
function post(obj) {
  let form = document.createElement("form");
  form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
  form.setAttribute("enctype", 'multipart/form-data"');
  form.setAttribute("action", '/');

  //Create temp form with obj data
  for(let key in obj) {
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          let hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "text");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", obj[key]);

          form.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
  }
  document.body.appendChild(form);  
  let formData = new FormData(form);
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST','http://127.0.0.1:7000/submit');
  xhr.send(formData);
  document.body.removeChild(form);
}
```

New Server-side code:

```
router.post('/', (req,res,)=>{
    //Multiparty handles formData sent
    let form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        console.log('Multiparty caught request');
        let newTask = fields;
            //If user is signed-in, data will be saved;
            if(req.user){
                newTask = Object.assign({owner: req.user._id},newTask);
                Task.create(newTask);
            }
        console.log(newTask);
        res.end();
      });
        res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

This seemed to solve my issue